# Optimizing performance for image displays

Tags: java, image, image-optimization

I am writing a web application that has a page that returns a list of results of objects that each have a profile photo.

I am unsure of how large I expect this page to get, but I want to account for it getting to a larger level. Right now, I am only returning 5-10 objects each with an associated photo, and I am seeing a performance decrease.

I am aware there are many resources on the internet regarding image optimization, and I have done some research, but am still lost as to what I should do to optimize this page.

I know that using **css-sprites** is an option, but these photos are added by members, so I'm not sure If I could keep up with updating the CSS Sprite.

I am also aware that some image types might be better for performance, but sometimes with a loss of compatibility(although I have read articles that argue against this, and say it is something of the past).

I am fairly new to the concept of needing to optimize images on my page, so if there is a more advanced technique that somebody believes might be over a more novice developers ability, then it might be the wrong thing for me.

Any advice would help. If I try one and am unable to figure out the answer, I can always try another.

**I realize this is something that can go on StackOverFlow's sister website regarding web design, but I would like to get the server side of it as well because there may be some fixes I need to make when I am uploading the file, so please no comments on how this is not fit for StackOverflow, Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a good way of optimisng images is using `cache`, and plus `thumbnail` them!

if you dont know about caching:

- this is good tutorial to start for
  webdesigners/ devlopers:[Cache Tutorial for web authors](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)`
- this is good tutorial on creating images into thumbnails using php and Gd(which comes default with php)
  just check incase
  [Create thumbnails using PHP and GD](http://icant.co.uk/articles/phpthumbnails/)`

Comment: by thumbnail them, do you mean just make them smaller when displaying them? I am doing that, but I have read that this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnail them server-side to the EXACT dimensions needed, then convert them to a jpeg. Also, if possible, just use one "default" photo for all of the users then load the individual profile photos via AJAX once the page has loaded.